# linux script that will delete files from previous month

Tags: linux

I am new in linux scripting and I have never created .sh file before.
I need to create a script that will delete all the files which are from previous month.
I have gone through the

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;
```

but find useless as days in a month can vary from 30 -31 days.
Please help me on this problem. thanks

Comment: Do you mean files that were last modified during the previous month?

Comment: so if today was 1st of June you want to delete everything from 1 to 31th May?

Answer (score 1):

Run below commands to delete last month file in working Directory.

1st you can see last moth files in working directory run

```
sudo find . -mtime +30
```

Numeric arguments can be specified as
   +n     for greater than n,
   -n     for less than n,
   n      for exactly n.

```
sudo find . -mtime +30  -delete
```

to delete all files in the systems you can run as below

```
  sudo find / -mtime +30  -delete
```

Comment: No one will like to delete all the files in the system. :|

Comment: you can try this   sudo find / -mtime +30  -delete

Comment: Deleting all files in the system is a bad example!

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off - how important is it your purge last month? I mean - if you run your script on May 1st, are you really expecting to delete the files from last night?

For most purposes - `find -mtime +30` is sufficient, as it's a rolling 30d window.

However, if you really want to 'last month and older' then you have to get a bit more creative, because Unix works on time stamps - in seconds. 30d in seconds is a fixed window, but as you note - 1 calendar month is not.

It gets worse yet if you bear in mind that 'last month' may well also be 'last year' as well.

So to get exactly one month ago:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -e 'print localtime -> add_months(-1);'
```

To turn that into a Unix timestamp:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -e 'print localtime -> add_months(-1) -> epoch;'
```

To actually figure out the time stamp of the start of the last month is slightly more complicated though - the easiest way is probably to do the above, and then 'figure out' the time stamp of the first day.

E.g.

```
perl -MTime::Piece -e 'print localtime->strptime(localtime->add_months(-1)->strftime("%Y%m"),"%Y%m);'
```

We subtract 1 month from today, reformat it as 'year/month' and then re-parse 'year/month' with no day to get the first day of the month.

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory bash solution. From the working directory containing the files to remove, you could run this

```
for i in $(ls -al | awk '/May/{print $NF}'); do rm -rf $i; done
```

It will explicitly match all files create in May and then remove them.

The ls -al command lists out the files with their dates and then the awk command matches the files with a date of May and then prints out only the file name. You can test it out before pulling the trigger by running this

```
ls -al | awk '/May/{print $NF}'
```

Once you are certain that the files being found are the ones you want to remove, you can run the for loop to remove them.